# Recovering measure support from the sequence of I.I.D random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Assume we have a Borel probability measure $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a sequence of $\mu$ distributed I.I.D. random variables $x_n$. Is there a limit formula for $supp(\mu)$, something like closure of limit points of $x_n$ or similar, which allows kind of asymptotic recovering of $supp(\mu)$ from observed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By f.i. https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Support_of_a_measure $supp(\mu)$ is the smallest closed set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mu(C^c) = 0$, $C^c$ the complement of $C$. Let $y := (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be any sample of $(x_n)$ (independent realizations of $\mu$) and $A := \{y_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $A_N := \{y_n \colon n \leq N\}$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Then by Borel-Cantelli with probability $1$ $A \subset C$, $A_N \uparrow A$ and $A$ is dense in $C$, in particular $\bar A = C$. Thus each sequence of iid random variables recovers the support (a.s.).

Comment: If I interpret your answer correctly, you essentially say that $\mu$-almost every realization will be a dense set inside the $supp(\mu)$ ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: thanks, I think that is what I wanted!

Comment: After some thinking I realized that even slightly stronger statement is true: any probability measure in $R^n$ is a weak limit of its averaged sum of Dirak measures on "iid realization" almost surely...

Answer (score 3):

that's basically the philosophy of Monte Carlo. So here is one suggestion: for $x_{n}$ iid uniform variables in the $supp(\mu)$ and generic integrable function $f$ we have by strong law of large numbers

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(x_{i})\to \int_{supp(\mu)}f(x)dx.$$

So by taking a localized $f$ eg. $f(x)=1_{B_{r}(x_{0})}(x)$ one can inspect the support of $\mu$.